# FIRST & LAST values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am having trouble querying some data. The table I am trying to pull the data from is a LOG table, where I would like to see changes in the values next to each other (example below)

Table:

```
+-----------+----+-------------+----------+------------+
| UNIQUE_ID | ID |    NAME     |   CITY   |    DATE    |
+-----------+----+-------------+----------+------------+
| xa220     |  1 | John Smith  | Berlin   | 2020.05.01 |
| xa195     |  1 | John Smith  | Berlin   | 2020.03.01 |
| xa111     |  1 | John Smith  | München  | 2020.01.01 |
| xa106     |  2 | James Brown | Atlanta  | 2018.04.04 |
| xa100     |  2 | James Brown | Boston   | 2017.12.10 |
| xa76      |  3 | Emily Wolf  | Shanghai | 2016.11.03 |
| xa20      |  3 | Emily Wolf  | Shanghai | 2016.07.03 |
| xa15      |  3 | Emily Wolf  | Tokyo    | 2014.02.22 |
| xa12      |  3 | Emily Wolf  | null     | 2014.02.22 |
+-----------+----+-------------+----------+------------+
```

Desired outcome:

```
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+
| ID |    NAME     |   CITY   | PREVIOUS_CITY |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | John Smith  | Berlin   | München       |
|  2 | James Brown | Atlanta  | Boston        |
|  3 | Emily Wolf  | Shanghai | Tokyo         |
|  3 | Emily Wolf  | Tokyo    | null          |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+
```

I have been trying to use FIRST and LAST values, however, cannot get the desired outcome.

```
select distinct id,
name, 
city, 
first_value(city) over (partition by id order by city) as previous_city
from test
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Use `lag` function to get the city for previous date and leave only the rows where current city and the result of `lag` are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LAG` function to get the city for previous date and display only the rows where current city and the result of lag are different:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, LAG(CITY, 1, CITY) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "DATE") LAG_CITY
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT ID, NAME, CITY, LAG_CITY AS PREVIOUS_CITY
FROM cte
WHERE
    CITY <> LAG_CITY OR
    CITY IS NULL AND LAG_CITY IS NOT NULL OR
    CITY IS NOT NULL AND LAG_CITY IS NULL
ORDER BY
    ID, "DATE" DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Some comments on how `LAG` is being used and its values checked are warranted.  We use the three parameter version of `LAG` here.  The second parameter means the number of records to look back, which in this case is 1 (the default).  The third parameter means the default value to use should a given record per `ID` partition be the *first*.  In this case, we use the default as the same `CITY` value.  This means that the first record would never appear in the result set.

For the `WHERE` clause above, a matching record is one for which the city and lag city are different, *or* for where one of the two be `NULL` and the other not `NULL`.  This is the logic needed to treat a `NULL` city and some not `NULL` city value as being different.